# How to map angular form input to make a post request?

Tags: angular, forms, api, interface, mapping

I need help mapping the form inputs to my interface so the body of my post request look like this .

```
  "ListCars": [
    {
    "Car": "Toyota",
    "Color" : "Red" ,
    "Year": "2015"
    }
    ],
    "Type" : "rav4",
    }
```

I'm currently getting this output from my form

```
  Car: Toyota
    Color : Red 
    Year: 2015
    Type : rav4
```

This is an example of my interface

```
expand interface Cars 
{
ListCars:  ListCars[],
Type: string ;
}
```

This is how  I'm getting the values from my form  and I'm making the request

component.ts

```
this.FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      Car: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      color: new FormControl('', [Validators.minLength(5), Validators.required]),
      year: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      type: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    });

submit(){
    if (this.reproGroup.valid) {
     const formValue: CarsInterface = this.FormGroup.value;

    this.service.postrequest(formValue.)
        .subscribe(response =>
      {

        });
      }
  }
```

service.ts

This is how my post request looks

```
 postrequest(carsInterface : CarsInterface ): Observable< output> {
      return this.http.post<output>(this .massReproDCQouteUrl, JSON.stringify(carsInterface ),
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is several ways to solve that

One is refactoring the FormGroup

```
this.FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  ListCars: this.formBuilder.array([
      this.formBuilder.group({
          Car: ['', Validators.required],
          color: ['', [Validators.minLength(5), Validators.required]],
           year: ['', Validators.required],
      })          
  ]),
  type: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

Another is changing de FormGroup value on submit

```
const { Car, color, year, type } = this.FormGroup.value;
const formValue: CarsInterface = {
  ListCars: [{ Car, color, year }],
  type
};
```

[Example on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rkiqt9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)